# Can Swift apps add appointments to the iOS appointment app via an Apple API call?

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I am writing a new app in Swift that deals with customer relationships.

Is there an Apple supplied API my app can call so that it can add appointments to that Apple supplied Calendar/appointment app?

I would rather not build my own appointment piece since Apple devices all have the Apple supplied appointment/calendar app.

Thoughts, anyone?

I have searched the internet but did not find any recent clues.  Perhaps one of you have been down this road already...

Comment: Appointment App? Do you mean Calendar? If so, EventKit.

Comment: Yes Calendar, if you mean the app that allows us to create appointments on our iPhone and see that on our iPad and Mac...yes, I think you have it right.  Apologize if I was a bit vague...EventKit, hmmm...is this library/framework old and/or written in Obj-C?